# R tree() / maptree() values for categorical splits

Tags: r, tree

I am trying to get a more meaningful version of the data plotted when a categorical predictor appears in the output of a tree function.

The values are airport codes: FLR, FUE, GOA, HER etc,

If I use tree() and

```
plot(Simulate.tree2); text(Simulate.tree2, pretty=1)
```

I get:
[image]

Which is not bad, but the codes are abbreviated and not clear.

If I use maptree() and

```
draw.tree(Simulate.tree2)
```

I get:

[image]

which is not at all helpful, since the letters just indicate the position of the value in a vector (I assume)

Is there a way in either package (or both) to get the actual values printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
plot(Simulate.tree2)
text(Simulate.tree1, pretty = 3)
```

From the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tree/tree.pdf), it looks like passing an integer to `pretty` sets the minimum length of the labels at that integer value. So for airport codes, you'd want 3.

Comment: I must have read that a dozen times and it didn't register. Thanks.